# Можно ли создать некий «предупредительный выстрел в воздух» для новичков?

Tags: предложение, модерация

Господа программисты, я новичок на сайте. Я зарегистрировался на *Stack Overflow* около года назад, но не бывал тут; постоянным посетителем стал только месяц назад.

Я задавал немного вопросов, с десяток наверное. Два вопроса были неудачные с точки зрения знатоков, я их удалил. Ни разу никого не оскорбил, матом тут не ору... Но меня на сегодня заблокировали; не могу задавать вопросы, мой последний вопрос ушёл в минус и трое потребовали его закрытия. Я спрашивал в комментариях, мол, отзовитесь, дайте объяснения, но тишина.

*Это не крик отчаяния, а констатация конкретного случая.*

Вопрос: можно ли придумать для новичков своего рода «предупредительный выстрел», мол, «батенька, еще один такой плохой вопрос и вы будете заблокированы»? А еще исключить возможность без объяснения выставлять минус вопросу и требования закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Закрытие - это и есть предупредительный выстрел для вопроса. Как только вопрос исправляют - он попадает в очередь голосования за открытие. По поводу того, почему не можете вопросы задавать - не в курсе.

Comment: а мне угадать почему следует закрыть?

Comment: 3 голоса из 5 за закрытие - это еще не закрытие. Могу посоветовать максимально детализировать вопрос - что, где, куда. Сейчас вопрос слишком размытый.

Comment: Arhad, благодарю...

Comment: я понял.вас...  проблема  в том, что я не имею представления как...  в той отрасли которую я знаю, я знаю как правильно  задать вопрос.... а тут как быть?  без коменнтов не справиться, а они молчат

Comment: Минимальная необходимая информация: где база, с чем ее нужно синхронизировать, как делаете сейчас (у вас git то всплывает, то исчезает), ну и ваш вопрос - как делать правильно? Просто последовательно объясняете ситуацию. Это примерно как код писать, чтобы придирчивывый компилятор вас правильно понял.

Comment: А вот если вы вопрос заводите не о том, как бы предупредить адекватных новичков что их скоро могут забанить, а о том, как адекватным новичкам успешно влиться в сообщество -- вот тогда всё встаёт на свои места. Оказывается, что дополнительные предупредительные выстрелы в воздух и не нужны, потому что на неадекватных они не действуют (просто после бана создадут новую учётку), а адекватные и так понимают, что -цатая блокировка -- это что-то неправильное. Как успешно влиться в сообщество вы не спросили, да и ответ-то поди знаете, верно?

Comment: Это автоматическая блокировка. Сайт временно блокирует возможность задавать вопросы, если статистика предыдущих вопросов не очень хороша. Предполагается, что вы можете улучшить эту статистику, исправив вопросы.

Comment: если быть откровенным, господа, не скажу, что знаю точно и не могу сказать обратного, но вы "динозавры", простите за сравнение.  не должны уставать делать замечание...  знайте , век учись век живи, дураком помрешь все ровно...  это я к тому что мне приятно, когда мне на мои ошибки указывают, всегда любил развиваться...  особенно в той отрасли, которую люблю...

Comment: если бы хотя бы один обыватель, который знает правило и имеет голос, написал бы сразу что не так с вопросом, то и темы бы данной не было...  все же вопрос я тут не зря задал, может кому то на ус намотается... как новичкам так и старожилам....

Comment: @Air, никто никому ничего не обязан, тем более делать кому-то замечания. У всех свои дела, и чтобы вопрос привлек достаточное внимание, это должен быть хороший годный вопрос. А вопрос из 2 строк таковым обычно не является. Здесь никто не обязан никого учить, как задавать вопросы. Есть справка, этого достаточно.

Comment: ребят, я понимаю, что никто ни кому не обязан ни чем....   согласен полностью...

Comment: А если бы новички читали правила stackoverflow, то сколько бы проблем отпало!! Не пришлось бы заставлять тыкать носом в каждую ошибку - раз. Не пришлось бы думать, как сделать выстрел попредупредительнее, чтобы не дай бог не обидеть... В ФИДО правильно говорили: прежде, чем писать в эху -- почитай её сначала в рид-онли пару месяцев, изучи правила.... Мне вот что непонятно: вы набрали 350+ репутации и до сих пор не нашли время прочитать справку на темы "что такое плохие вопросы" и "как написать хороший" и главное -- что вас кто-то обязан учить?